# View Attachments in XPage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpinc

I need to view file attachments (doc scans as JPG, TIFF, PDF, etc.)  in Notes. There is an article [here](http://web.zagreb.hr/help/help7_client.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/125c8ab1e3c1f00f8525704a004d9b30?OpenDocument) which describes to do that through the standard Notes UI. Do not know how to call that correctly, sorry. What I need is to view file attachments with XPage.

Is there a way to use the Notes `Attachment -> View` functionality within XPage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPages is first and foremost a server technology based on JSF. You access an XPages application through a browser (in case of XPiNC: the browser embedded into the Notes client).

So anything you want to 'view' is bound/limited by your browser's capabilities.

The Notes client has an OEM library called OutsideIn (afaik now owned by Oracle) that could render many file formats without the original application. This library is a client library, not a server code. Domino treats attachments as binary blob that get delivered when requested and it is the viewers task to make sense of them (the browser or whatever application reacts to the URL).

In case you are wondering what the attachment URLs are, check out this article: http://notessensei.com/blog/2010/06/attachment-urls-in-xpages.html

Comment: Thanks for this infos. So when notes client utilizes `Outside In` to view all kinds of file formats directly, how can I utilize it using XPage (CSJS) ?

Comment: OutsideIn DLL are on the client only. Not in the browser.

Comment: There seems to be a missunderstanding. So I try to make it clear : I need a solution for an XPage app running in Lotus Notes. When this is the `client` you are talking about then again my question is how to to utilize `Outside In` ?

Comment: It does not have a published API. Your best bet might be a composite application where you trigger view attachment from a classic form. For XPages in the Notes clients it helps to mention XPiNC since XPages questions are mostly about web

Comment: Okay I learn ;-)   I need to trigger view attachements from XPiNC (XPage in Notes Client). How to achieve that ?

Comment: That's quite a challenge. You need a button in a classic form that does that using @commands. https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/mobile/#!/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ATTACHMENTVIEW.html  Then expose that to a composite app and trigger that using a client action in XPages. You need to make sure the attachment is selected. Composite apps are here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/mobile/#!/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_COMPAPP8_INTRO.html

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I'll give it a try ;-)